# No glyph for U+000D in font Helvetica

Tags: pdfbox, boxable

How to solve this for pdfbox with boxable.

I am getting in table.draw as

No glyph for U+000D in font Helvetica

What to do.I am building table with boxable

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding

Answer (score 4):

That error tells you that your strings you use to fill the tables contain CR (carriage return) characters.

Do not use control characters (like CR, LF, TAB, ...) in those string as your software stack does not interpret them to mean something like a line break; instead it tries to interpret it as a glyph in the font which it fails doing.

If you need to break lines in boxable tables, try using `<p>` or `<br>` instead. According to their [README](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable), they support

> HTML tags in cell content (not all! `<p>,<i>,<b>,<br>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>`)