# PDFBOX : U+000A ('controlLF') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, pdfbox

When trying to print a PDF page using Java and the `org.apache.pdfbox` library, I get this error:

> PDFBOX : U+000A ('controlLF') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Comment: Related: [No glyph for U+000D in font Helvetica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738550/no-glyph-for-u000d-in-font-helvetica)

Comment: If you want to print INTO pdf, use the TextToPDF tool, or use its source code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[PROBLEM] The String you are trying to display contains a newline character.

[SOLUTION] Replace the String with a new one and remove the newline:

```
text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: Depending on the use case at hand, you might want to replace with a single space instead of an empty string.

Comment: I am not using \n but still I see the below error  

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+FFFD ('.notdef') is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding


Error if text is  : Habitación

but works fine when : Habitaci\u00F3n

Comment: With \r it's not working better use <br> if You are concatenating strings. For \r error is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+000D ('controlCR') is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Answer (score 11):

The answer selected for this post works, replacing all instances of \n and \r from your string, if you know that it's a \n or \r character that's causing your problem. I've discovered that there are lots of different characters that will produce this error. Here's a sampling of those that I've found:

```
U+2010 ('hyphentwo') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+2033 ('second') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+00A0 ('nbspace') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+FFFD ('.notdef') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+03BC ('mugreek') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+039C ('Mu') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+2212 ('minus') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+0141 ('Lslash') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+2103 ('centigrade') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
U+25AA ('H18543') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

In my case, I've simply chosen to remove any special character that's not included in my font. I used the solution from this page:

[Remove illegal characters from string with PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228567/remove-illegal-characters-from-string-with-pdfbox)

Comment: Link doesn't exist anymore :/

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a similar issue too (using pdfbox 2.0.11), my error was:

```
U+00A0 ('nbspace') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

Which was strange because checking the WinAnsiEncoding for the char name (int value 160) returned `space`, but the internal classes of pdfbox was returning the name `nbspace`.

The solution for me was upgrading to pdfbox 2.0.21.

Comment: That was this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4891  There is a follow-up bug that will be fixed in 2.0.22  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4944

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to retain the newline addition, i.e you indeed want your text to split and appear the later part in new line, then you can simply replace the **\n** with an HTML **break** tag, like below below .

`return text.replace("\n","<br>");`

:)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to set a new line using "\n" in a string  . you can try         PDPageContentStream.newLineAtOffset(x,y)   to add a new line

```
  PDFont font =  PDType1Font.HELVETICA ; 

  PDDocument doc    = new PDDocument();
  PDPage page = new PDPage();
  PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
  content.beginText();
  content.moveTextPositionByAmount(10, 700);
  content.setFont(font, 12);
  content.drawString("start text   ");
  content.newLineAtOffset(0, -15);
  content.drawString("text in new line  ");        
  content.endText();
  content.close();
  doc.addPage(page);
  doc.save("file.pdf");
```

and the pdf [image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove all chars that can not be encoded by the font you use for PDF writing you can do something like:

```
PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;    
public static void erasesControlCharacters(List<String> values) {
    String charSet = font.getFontDescriptor().getCharSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String test = values.get(i);
        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < test.length(); charIndex++) {
            if (WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE.contains(test.charAt(charIndex)) && charSet.contains(test.substring(charIndex, charIndex + 1))) {
                b.append(test.charAt(charIndex));
            }
        }
        values.set(i, b.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to change a font like :

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("C:\\Users\\dw\\Desktop\\FZLTXHJW.TTF"));
```

Replace "FZLTXHJW.TTF" with the font you have and it should support your text encoding.

Answer (score -2):

One of thing we found and helped is -- while you are making a HTTP call with this special encoding data to an external system - make sure you encode your JSON (if json) body to utf-8 charset before doing a API post. something like this below

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(bodyJsonParams, "UTF-8"));
```