# Easiest method to convert JSON to PDF in java?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, pdf

I use the Java Spring Boot framework and I need to convert my Json to PDF. The problem is that all text in the PDF is written in one line, which means that line breaks do not work. As a result, I get a PDF in which the first line is blank or an empty file.

```
 @GetMapping("/pdf/{Id}")
    @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_OPERATOR", "ROLE_GUEST"})
    public ResponseEntity<PDDocument> findOnePdfByIdJob(@PathVariable("Id") Long id) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Job job = jobService.findById(id);

        if (job == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(job);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement je = jp.parse(jsonInString);
        String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);


        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 12);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.showText(jsonInString);
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

        document.save("pdfBoxHelloWorld.pdf");
        document.close();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(document);
    }
```

As a result, I get a PDF in which everything is written in one line. That is, the text cannot be read .... The first line becomes just a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `Gson` if you already use `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper`. Just enable `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` feature and `ObjectMapper` will generate pretty `JSON` as well. Also, you need split `JSON` on lines and add each line one by one using `newLine` method from `PDPageContentStream`.

Simple app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class PdfApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // enable pretty printing
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        // read map from file
        MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, mapType);

        // generate pretty JSON from map
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        // split by system new lines
        String[] strings = json.split(System.lineSeparator());

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 12);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 725);
        for (String string : strings) {
            contentStream.showText(string);
            // add line manually
            contentStream.newLine();
        }
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

        document.save("pdfBoxHelloWorld.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Generates `PDF` file with content like below:
[image]

See also:

- [PDFBox - Adding Multiple Lines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_adding_multiple_lines.htm)
- [PDFBOX : U+000A ('controlLF') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644570/pdfbox-u000a-controllf-is-not-available-in-this-font-helvetica-encoding)

Comment: Thank, but when i try to use this example it  cannot find one of the fonts, if I understood correctly:                                                                                         
2019-03-23 19:48:30.701 ERROR 7700 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      : Could not load font file: C:\Windows\FONTS\mstmc.ttf                                                                                                  When i debugging a program crashes on the line: contentStream.beginText ();