# Save extracted variable value in a pdf file using JSR223 PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

How to save the extracted variable value(text/content) in a pdf file using JSR223 PostProcessor in JMeter??
let say variable name ${data} .
Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a library like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for this

1. Add it and all its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
3. The simplest code to write a JMeter Variable into a PDF file would be something like:

   ```
   def document = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument()
   def page = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage()
   document.addPage(page)

   def font = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD

   // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
   def contentStream = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream(document, page)

   // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
   contentStream.beginText()
   contentStream.setFont(font, 12)
   contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700)
   contentStream.drawString(vars.get('data'))
   contentStream.endText()

   // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
   contentStream.close()

   // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
   document.save('path-to-your-file.pdf')
   document.close()
   ```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache PDFBox Cookbook - Document Creation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, Thanks for your valuable comment. but when I have run the above snippet code get some error like " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+000D ('controlCR') is not available in the font Helvetica-Bold, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
" , so can you please tell me what is this error ??

Comment: Your `${data}` variable has some characters (i.e. line breaks) which are not allowed in PDF strings, you either need to remove the line breaks or split the `${data}` variable into an array of strings and call `drawSting()` function for each line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644570/pdfbox-u000a-controllf-is-not-available-in-this-font-helvetica-encoding